# Считывание нажатия на клавиатуру

Tags: c++, qt

Как можно считать нажатие клавиши за одно, а не в стандартной форме: сигнал - пауза - сигнал (пока происходит нажатие)?

Мне нужно что бы эта форма была такой: нажатие клавиши - непрекращающийся сигнал.

Я попытался считывать нажатие в этой стандартной форме и приравнивать булевое значение - True, а когда  клавиша будет отжата, то False, но в итоге все работало инверсивно и с задержкой.

```
void Widget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *Kevent){
    if (Kevent->key() == Qt::Key_A){
        bt = true; 
    }
}

void Widget::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *Revent){
    if (Revent->key() == Qt::Key_A){
        bt = false;
    }
}
```

как можно считывать нажатую клавишу по человечески?

Comment: "непрекращающийся сигнал" в цифровой системе невозможен. У вас код правильный приведен. Подозреваю, ваше "инверсивно и с задержкой" произошло из-за того, что вы неправильно обрабатываете флаг `bt`

Comment: А просто QEvent в виджет не прилетают пока кнопка нажата?

Comment: Вообще-то, притензия к разработчикам QT вполне обоснованна - KeyDown и KeyUp сделали, а "человеческое" и "сахарное" KeyPress забыли, хотя сами, вроди бы, надстройка, а не низкий уровень

Answer (score 0):

Можно через таймер:

```
Widget::Widget(): _timer() {
    // Гавкаем "наружу" при нажатой клавише
    connect(&_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Widget::wofwof);
}

void Widget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *Kevent){
    if (Kevent->key() == Qt::Key_A)
        _timer.start(1000); // Частота 1 сек       
}

void Widget::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *Revent){
    // Таймер работает - значит была нажата нужная клавиша
    if( _timer.isActive() )
        _timer.stop();
}
```

Заголовок:

```
class Widget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget();
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *Kevent);
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *Kevent);
signals:
    void wofwof();
private:
    QTimer _timer;
}
```